# 2sxc icon picker not showing certain fontawesome icons in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm working with Tutorial App of 2sxc ;"Tutorial Custom Icon Font and Picker",and using font awesome.

The icon picker shows lots of fonts but one particular one "fa-graduation-cap" is just not showing up
http://fontawesome.io/icon/graduation-cap/

I've looked into the fontawesome css file and its mentioned there, but in font picker search it just doesn't show up.

Can you help me guide to a particular file so it starts showing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug, after looking into FontAwesome CSS file if multiple classes are defined for an icon then the Icon Picker will only get the first css class.

Example in terms of Graduation Cap icon in the css it was listed as

```
.fa-mortar-board:before,
.fa-graduation-cap:before {
    content: "\f19d";
}
```

Hence the icon picker was only listing the icon with Mortar Board name and skipping Graduation cap.

2sxc can you kindly fix this in your angular js code so search picks up all the class names?